# Trying to concatenate strings with <<

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

I've been studying java programming for half a year but now I'm trying to learn c++ too.

I'm using minGW and codeblocks. My problem is that I'm trying to copy a file from one path to another. This works great with this:

```
system("copy c:\\test.txt c:\\test2.txt");
```

but when I'm trying this it doesn't work ( currPath and dest are strings)

```
system("copy " << currPath << " " << "c:\\" << dest << "\\hej.exe" << end1);
```

I'm getting the error:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' in '"copy " << currPath'
```

The strings currpath and dest only contains one \, but I dont think that is the problem.

Comment: I would like to know who downvoted this question and what was his reason to do so. Maybe it's not the best answer ever, but vaild for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `operator<<` you are trying to use there is associated with C++ stream. You are not currently using streams, so you should concatenate the string using `operator+` of `std::string`:

```
auto str = std::string("copy ") + currPath + " c:\\" + dest + "\\hej.exe\n";
system(str.c_str());
```

or, using [C++14 literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s):

```
auto str = "copy "s + currPath + " c:\\" + dest + "\\hej.exe\n";
```

Comment: Addendum: Be aware that the temporary string is destroyed at the end of the expression. Not that it's of any consequence here.

Comment: Do i have to insert an extra backslash, since in the string there's only one backslash between the folders? I thought if it interprets the backslah as an escape character?

Comment: @Johan `"c:\\"` will [be interpreted](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/339cebd1f03cea24) as `"c:\"`.

Comment: @Jefffrey Thanks, was a little confused by all the slashes for a while but now everything works. Couldn't  upvote your answer by that time either so did it now instead, thank you so much :)

Comment: And i thought the << operator was like the + operator in java too :P

Comment: @Johan Just remember that "string" + "other" doesn't work like you would expect because `"string"` is a `const char*` so the + that is selected is the one between pointers. Make sure that every time you want to concatenate, the first string is actually an `std::string`. Either with `std::string(...)` or by appending `s` to a C-string (like `"copy "s`).

Comment: Ok I will have that mind from now on. C++ is 10 times harder than Java if you ask me :P Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `operator<<` to put strings together, you need to use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::ostringstream strm;
strm << "copy " << currPath << " " << "c:\\" << dest << "\\hej.exe";
system(strm.str().c_str());
```

That can be wrapped since it doesn't need to last longer than this line:

```
system((std::ostringstream{} << "copy " << currPath << " " 
             << "c:\\" << dest << "\\hej.exe").str().c_str());
```

but that's a bit hard on the eyes.